# How to avoid index number being appended to file name in MultiResourceItemWriter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch

I am using `org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemWriter` for creating multiple files per `SQL` record. Files are getting created but an index number is being appended to each file. e.g.:

```
load1.xml
load2.xml
load3.xml
```

I have a mechanism in place to add timestamp in file name instead but I do not want the index number to be appended. Is there any way to avoid the index number being appended to file name?

Thanks!

Comment: Use custom [ResourceSuffixCreator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/ResourceSuffixCreator.html)

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks!